# Making text align to the left in first cell of flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I've got a flexbox code working in my file, this is just the relevant parts of the whole file:

```css
.tbl {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.cell {
  flex: 4;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.cell:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 2;
}
.cell.span4-5 {
  flex: 8 24px;                    /*  col 4,5 flex-grow/border/padding  */
}
.cell.span3-4 {
  flex: 8 24px;                    /*  col 3,4 flex-grow/border/padding  */
}
.cell.span3-5 {
    align-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 12 36px;                   /*  col 3,4,5 flex-grow/border/padding  */
}

.cell.span1-1 {
   width: 60px;
}

div.atalign1 {
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.row:first-child .cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;         /*  center horiz. */
  align-items: center;             /*  center vert. */
}
.row .cell {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
  <div class="atalign1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell span3-5">Text</div>
    <div class="cell span1-1">$50,000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell span3-4">Content</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="atalign1">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="cell span3-5">This is my text. This is my text</div>
    <div class="cell span1-1">$3,000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell span3-4">Content</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

In the second div, the text is aligned to the left; for the first one, the text will NOT align to the left, even when I tried text-align: left;

If anyone could help I'd really appreciate this!

Comment: You have centered the text in CSS: `.row:first-child .cell`. Try changing `justify-content` to `flex-start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class is causing the problem:

```
.row:first-child .cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;         /*  center horiz. */
  align-items: center;             /*  center vert. */
}
```

The text is actually aligned to the left, you're just justifing it and aligning the item so it's going crazy. See snippet below:

```css
.tbl {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.cell {
  flex: 4;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.cell:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 2;
}
.cell.span4-5 {
  flex: 8 24px;                    /*  col 4,5 flex-grow/border/padding  */
}
.cell.span3-4 {
  flex: 8 24px;                    /*  col 3,4 flex-grow/border/padding  */
}
.cell.span3-5 {
    align-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 12 36px;                   /*  col 3,4,5 flex-grow/border/padding  */
}

.cell.span1-1 {
   width: 60px;
}

div.atalign1 {
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}




.row .cell {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
  <div class="atalign1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell span3-5">Text</div>
    <div class="cell span1-1">$50,000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell span3-4">Content</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="atalign1">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="cell span3-5">This is my text. This is my text</div>
    <div class="cell span1-1">$3,000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell span3-4">Content</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.row:first-child .cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;         /*  center horiz. */
  align-items: center;             /*  center vert. */
}
```

Because you have the div containing the text set to `display: flex`, the elements inside (direct descendants) will follow the `justify-content` and `align-items` rules. In this case `justify-content` is causing the text to be centered horizontally, while `align-items` is centering it vertically.

You can set it to `justify-content: flex-start` to align the text to the left while keeping it vertically centered.